# In python, I'm trying to count each element in a list using a for loop, but it returns the element occurrence n many times

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscripter

This function returns the element occurrence n many times:

```
def cold_compress():
    l = int(input())
    inp_list = []
    num_list = []
    for lines in range(l):
        b = input()
        inp_list.append(b)
        print(b)

    for item in inp_list:
        for x in item:
            print(item.count(x))
```

For example:
if my input is:

eeewwww

33jjji

...it will output:

3

3

3

4

4

4

4

2

2

3

3

3

1

How do I avoid this?

Comment: What output did you expect instead?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot I expected it to output 3 4 2 3 1, the amount of how many times each element appeared in a list.

Comment: Is for-loop a requirement?

Comment: If there's another way to do it

Comment: `for x in item: print(item.count(x))` repeats the printing. You don't need that loop.

Comment: You should really organize your code in a more logical manner. It makes little sense to have a function which counts the frequency of characters in a string take it's input from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Counter()**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the elements inside a list

Sample code:

```
from collections import Counter
listr = ["one","two","three","three","three","three",]

print(dict(Counter(listr)))
```

OUTPUT

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 1, 'three': 4}
```

Implementing the Counter() in your code:

```
from collections import Counter

def cold_compress():
    listr = list(input())
    print(dict(Counter(listr)))

cold_compress()
```